# How to properly access method from another function within class?

Tags: java, android, class

I've never done much Java programming, mostly all PHP / RUBY / Javascript so I'm not entirely sure how to probably go about accessing the `wLock.release()` from `onDestroy`?

```
public class SlammedNavigatorActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "SN Wake Lock");
        wLock.acquire();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        wLock.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert the local variable `wLock` to a private field:

```
public class SlammedNavigatorActivity extends DroidGap {
  private PowerManager.WakeLock wLock;


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    wLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "SN Wake Lock");
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it an instance variable:

```
public class SlammedNavigatorActivity extends DroidGap {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wLock;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.wLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "SN Wake Lock");
        wLock.acquire();

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        this.wLock.release();
    }
}
```

Why don't you learn the language basics before doing Android programming? Read the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), or a good book about Java.

Answer (score 0):

Make wLock a class member

```
public class SlammedNavigatorActivity extends DroidGap {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wLock;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "SN Wake Lock");
        wLock.acquire();

    }

    public void onDestroy() {

        wLock.release();
    }
}
```